# How to detect if the conversion failed in c++0x

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I tried to perform a string to int conversion as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i;
    char *str = "12a3";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    ss >> i;
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //prints 12
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4323417f49f49ca)

But the resul wasn't one that I expected. I'm a Java so honestly I was waiting for some exception to be thrown. But it wasn't. Is it possible to perform such casting in a safe-way without the legacy `atoi` function.

Note, that I'm in `C++0x` therefor cannot use `std::stoi`.

Comment: 12 makes sense, given that 'a' in the string.  What value would you consider a success?

Comment: @donjuedo I want that some exception is thrown, or a special value indicating the unsuccessful cast is returned.... something like that?

Comment: maybe this:  http://ideone.com/Mapgbk

Comment: The stream tries to read as much as it can. It reads `12` and sees that there's nothing valid afterwards but since it was able to read anything at all the extraction is considered valid.

Comment: @0x499602D2 So, when the stream fails it should probably set a badbit to true, therefore the `operator!` shoud have returned true. But it didn't. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0ef3d0b82583213) Couldn't you explain why?

Comment: You could always use [`std::strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: Consider the difference between "12a3" and "12 3" Both stop at the first non digit and return success. The stream operators are designed to be stupid and simple and cover the common usecases. What you want to do is read into a string, and then use a smarter string-to-int parser like strtol.

Comment: @DmitryBundin The extraction did not fail as it successfully read `12`. If it didn't read anything at all then `failbit` would be set, but this is not the case.

Comment: Your mistake here is in considering this a "failure". That's why all the searching you've been doing on the topic for the past few days has come up empty. It's not a "failure" to convert: it's that you expected the entire stream buffer to be requisite input for the conversion, but that's not how streams work.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct behaviour. The operation to `>>` into an `int` succeeded, and this is correct.

You have to ask a different question. The test you really want to perform is: "after I successfully read an `int`, are there any more characters which are leftover in the stream and have not yet been processed?"

Consider `cin`. When you do

```
int x, y;
std::cin >> x;
std::cin >> y;
```

it reads as much as it can from standard input into `x`, stopping at the first non-digit. Then, if there is just some whitespace after the first number, then it will attempt to read a number after the whitespace and store that number in `y`.

All input streams (whether `cin` or an instance `stringstream`) are expected to contain many strings/numbers/whatever. Each `>>` simply reads as much as it can (successfully).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach I know of.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::string num;
    long i;
    char *str = "12a3";
    char * endp;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    ss >> num;
    i = strtol(num.c_str(), // string to convert as a C style string, 
               &endp, //pointer to be updated with character that ended the conversion
               10); //base of number conversion
    if (*endp != '\0')
    {
        //didn't read whole string. conversion failed
    }
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //prints 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test both unsuccessful stream reading and *incomplete* stream reading:

```
ss >> i;
if (!ss || !ss.eof()) {
  throw std::invalid_argument("Could not convert to int");
}
```

Comment: Is `!ss.eof()` always the same as 'incomplete'? If you read the last character, `char c; ss >> c;` then the stream would be empty, but I think the EOF flag will not yet be set. Does "EOF" mean "the last character has been read", or "an attempt has been made to read past the last character"?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You're right, but the OP is not reading into a `char`.

Comment: Would testing `ss.peek() == EOF` be better?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments we concluded that your goal is to determine whether a string consists solely of a valid representation of a number.

C, and by extension C++ has always focused on stream I/O and therefore stream-like numeric conversions.  The consequence of that is that `scanf`, `istream >>`, `atoi`, and `strol` all stop at the first character that is NOT part of a valid number.

You goal then is to determine whether the input is fully consumed, or if there are trailing "garbage" characters.   The simplest approach is to use strtol which will return a pointer to the first unconsumed character.

```
char * endptr;
long i = strtol (str, &endptr, 10); 
bool valid = *endptr == '\0';
```

This will still fail if your input looks like this:  "  123  ", because the  scan will stop at the space character following the '3'.

If your requirements are that trailing spaces are acceptable, your code will need to examining the string that begins at *endptr after the call, to determin if it is an acceptable suffix, or it could trim the input string before doing the test.

Answer (score -1):

When the operator `>>` finds a result that it can't use, it sets `failbit` on the stream, and the stream itself will evaluate as `false`:

```
if(!(ss >> i)) {  // or ss >> i; if(!ss) or if(ss.fail())
    // the conversion failed, do whatever you need to here.
    ss.clear(); // reset the fail flag so you can read from the stream again

    // you can use ss.ignore() to skip bad input if you want to move on to other parts
}
```

Comment: Please be careful: The expression `! ss >> i` is parsed as `(!ss) >> i`

Comment: @dyp Well, the `operator!` returns false anyway. I really don't understand why... [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23a62b34d54af408)

Comment: @DmitryBundin The formatted input of numbers is based on `num_get`, which consumes characters until the first invalid character, and then tries conversion. I think it mimics the behaviour of `scanf`

Comment: @dyp So, there's no way to check if the string a valid number string or not with the `std::stringstream`. Will I have to use `atoi` or `strtol`?

Comment: atoi and strtol behave the same way.  A non-numeric character stops the scan.  If you want to check the entire string to see if it consists solely of a valid string representation of a number, that's a different problem.

Comment: @DaleWilson Many thanks. That's exactly what I wanted to hear... If you posted it as an answer I would accept it.